# How to get CPU utilization on jsp

Tags: java, jsp, cpu-usage

I need to get the cpu usage of the current process using jsp.

My scenario is like when user navigate from one page to other I need to check the cpu utilization, memory usage of the process.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634580/cpu-load-from-java

Comment: One difference to the similar issue is that the process running JSP may have very restricted rights.

Comment: @Eric J.: JSP runs at server machine, not at client machine.

Comment: @BalusC: Yes, but it's good security practice to run internet-facing services with the minimum set of privileges they need to get the job done.  I don't know what permissions are required to directly read CPU utilization, but I'm guessing it's more than the minimum to serve JSP pages.

Comment: @Eric J.: That's more an issue of JVM privileges at the host machine. You may indeed be prohibited from accessing this information at "3rd party" hosting. But at dedicated/colocated host this shouldn't be an issue. And this applies to Java in general, not just JSP.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this on every request, also in production (although I highly question the need for this, it would only make it more CPU-expensive), then grab [JMX](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/package-summary.html). If you want to do this for testing/profiling purposes (which would make more sense), then grab a [Java profiler](http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers).

As to the JSP-targeted question, JSP is just a Java based view technology. Raw Java code belongs in a real Java class. If you want to go for JMX, then you rather want to do this in a `Filter` which is mapped on the `url-pattern` of interest, e.g. `*.jsp`.